Trapping a function call with a proxy does not intercept the arguments
I want to intercept function calls and found that proxies can do that as shown here on MDN using the apply method. However what I quickly found out is that the params passed to the function are not intercepted so if you have params that can be expressions like in the case of tagged template literals for example the apply method does not intercept the execution of the tagged template and it`s expressions, why is that and is there any way to do that other than creating a wrapper function? I think the arguments should be intercepted as well feels like a bug in the proxy implementation to me.


// create tagged template function
function template(strings, ...keys) {
 console.log("tmp fn");
 
  return (...values) => {
    const dict = values[values.length - 1] || {};
    const result = [strings[0]];
    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
      const value = Number.isInteger(key) ? values[key] : dict[key];
      result.push(value, strings[i + 1]);
    });
    return result.join("");
  };
}

// Trapping a function call with proxy 
const taggedTemplate = new Proxy(template, {
  apply(target, thisArg, argArray) {
    console.log("apply");
    return target(...argArray)
  }
});

// some fn for the template
function Num() {
 console.log("Not intercepted Num() call")
 return 5
};

// use template
taggedTemplate`my fav number is ${Num()}`




This is just normal behaviour. If you have a function called within an expression that in turn is an argument to an outer function call, then the final argument passed to the outer function call is already evaluated before that outer function is called. You have not trapped it. If you want to trap the Num call, you'll have to create a proxy for it.

thats my point even if the num call is a proxy I can`t trap it with the outer trap

What do you mean with "outer trap". If you create a proxy for Num, proxying its apply, and call that proxy in your template literal, then that apply will be called.

that`s still called after the taggedTemplate in my example, I need to run something before the taggedTemplate argument gets evaluated.

Num is called before the taggedTemplate call. If you need something to run before the taggedTemplate argument gets evaluated, then your trap comes too late. You need to trap Num calls with a proxied version of it.


I want to intercept function calls and found that proxies can do that

Far too complicated. All you need is a wrapper function:
// Trapping a function call with another function
const taggedTemplate = (...argArray) => {
  console.log("apply");
  return target(...argArray);
};

The proxy doesn't achieve anything else here.

I quickly found that the params passed to the function are not intercepted. Why is that?

Because only taggedTemplate is a proxy (or wrapped function), and the apply trap triggers when that particular taggedTemplate function object is called. There is no proxy involved in Num(). The expression taggedTemplate`my fav number is ${Num()}`  is no different than doing
const value = Num();
taggedTemplate`my fav number is ${value}`


Is there any way to do that?

No.
